# How can inner join like this can be converted Sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm primarily trying to see how would you perform inner join here.

```
    SELECT * From "Users" as biz
INNER JOIN "Deals" as d
        ON biz.id = d."UserId" 
     WHERE (biz.latitude BETWEEN 18 AND 21) 
       AND (biz.longitude BETWEEN -78 AND -73);
```

this is what I got from documentation... but not sure how to proceed further

```
Deals.find({ where: { }, include: [User]})
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For `inner join` all you need is `required : true` :**

```
Deals.find({ 
        where: { }, 
        include: [{
            model : User ,
            required : true // This will make your inner join
        }]})
```

> NOTE : Use `findAll` or `findOne` instead of just `find`